# Page Speed Performance (shown in Google AdSense) on Blogspot Dynamic Template

Tags: google-adsense, blogger, page-speed

In Google AdSense, the Scorecard complains the **Page Speed Performance** of Google Blogger is not good ( marked as Red ).

Note: In my Blogger site, I'm using Dynamic Template.

Is there anything I can do to improve the speed ? or it is a false alarm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Google site speed anayizer tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to give you a break down of were the time is being spent loading the page.

To get the most detail report out of it try using the [Chrome or Firefox (firebug) plugins](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions)

Comment: I installed PageSpeed Chrome extension, but I can't change according to most of the advice, e.g. enable content expiring & caching

Comment: Thats the limitations of blogspot, id advise trying to optimise were you can, also try compress all your images - logos, blog posts, background ect locally on your machine and re uploading them, often optimising 1 400kb to 150kb can count more than compressing 1000s of lines of code